# Why do I get core dump when I try to free a char pointer allocated with malloc?

Tags: c, malloc, free

I'm trying to learn about the basics in C and I can't quite get `malloc()` and `free()` to work.

This is my code that's going to print a word in the center of the screen depending on input. (removed some declarations and includes to shorten it)

```
char *bridge_text;
char menu1[] = "Key input:  \n\t n. car arrive north \
                            \n\t s. car arrive south \
                            \n\t r. empty bridge \
                            \n\t q. quit";
int main()
{
    bridge_text = malloc(sizeof(char)*(LEN+1)); //misprinted here before

    initscr();
    getmaxyx(stdscr,row, col);

    mvprintw(2, 4, menu1);
    refresh();
    while(run)
    {
        switch(getchar())
        {
            case 'q':
                run = 0;
                break;
            case 'n':
                /*not shown: char north[] = "NORTH";*/
                bridge_text = north; 
                break;
            case 's':
                bridge_text = south;
                break;
            case 'r':
                bridge_text = empty;
                break;
            default:
                bridge_text = empty;
                break;
        }

        mvprintw(row/2, (col-5)/2, bridge_text);
        refresh();
    }
    endwin();

    /* adding free() here results in core dump. */
    free(bridge_text);

    return 0;}
```

I use gcc with cygwin and the program is executed properly and I can quit the program using 'q'-key, however...

- If first press `'n'`, `'e'` or `'r'` (assign `bridge_text` a string) and
  then try to exit, it results in a core-dump. This works fine if I
  remove `free()`

I do have an error when running executables with cygwin: *

> fatal error MapViewOfFileEx shared 5'(0x66) Win 32 error 6.

maybe that's the problem but I assumed it wasn't related to this.

Comment: delete `bridge_text = malloc(sizeof(LEN+1));` and `free(bridge_text);`

Comment: You need to study the basics of pointers before attempting dynamic memory allocation. The problem is that you aren't doing string assignment correctly.

Comment: You can use concatenation of adjacent string literals instead of line continuation: `"\tn. car arrive north\n"` `"\ts. car arrive south\n"` each on its own line.

Comment: sizeof(LEN+1) is a misprint. I was trying both 
    (LEN+1) 
and 
    sizeof(char)*(LEN+1) 
so I accidently typed like that. Is 
    sizeof(char)*(LEN+1) 
any good?

Comment: sizeof(char) is ALWAYS 1 in C.  so remove that expression from the parameter to malloc(), as it has no effect and just clutters the code.

Comment: where is 'LEN' defined?   what is its' value?  where are 'row' and 'col' defined?

Comment: the code block beginning with switch(getchar()) is not handling the '\n' that follows each character

Comment: the menu1 is never being displayed to the user.

Comment: @user3629249 I'm using ncurses, so because of `initscr()` it doesn't wait for '\n'. It's the terminal setting that makes it wait for '\n' before processing input, not `getchar` in my understanding. Also `menu1` is printed to the ncurses-screen at `mvprintw` then it is made sure to be shown on screen on every call to `refresh`. _(I didn't include all definitions, to shorten the question)_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While doing

```
 bridge_text = north;
```

and simmilar *assignments*, you're **overwriting** the actual pointer returned by `malloc()`. Now, calling `free()` with non-dynamically allocated pointer (memory) is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). If you want, you can [refer this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27876923/2173917).

Actually, to *copy* the content to already allocated memory, you can (and should) use [`strcpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy). Otherwise, by *assigning*, you're also creating [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), as the original pointer is lost.

Then,

```
 bridge_text = malloc(sizeof(LEN+1));
```

is also wrong. You need to change that to,

```
 bridge_text = malloc(LEN+1);   //sizeof(char) is 1 in c
```

After that, don't forget to check for the success of `malloc()`, too.

Comment: I think the real trick here is to never malloc in the first place, and simply point bridge_text to the chosen direction

Comment: @Eregrith yes, that can also be another approach, but in that case, `bridge_text` elemnts cannot be modified, right?

Comment: Yes but based on the code and the only call being `mvprintw(row/2, (col-5)/2, bridge_text);` (a print I guess), I think the `bridge_text` pointer is only there as a selection pointer

Answer (score 4):

Problems

1. `sizeof(LEN+1)` will evaluate to size of an integer
2. Dynamically allocated memory is lost when string is assigned

Change

```
bridge_text = malloc(sizeof(LEN+1));
```

to

```
bridge_text = malloc(LEN + 1);
```

and instead of assigning `bridge_text = north`, use `strcpy`

```
strcpy(bridge_text, north);
```

Comment: It would be also nice if you explained why should it be done.

Comment: @Shreevardhan Yes. But it was not answering the question at the time

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `free()` on a non-dynamically allocated pointer.

What you `malloc()`'d is lost when you do `bridge_text = north;`

Answer (score 0):

`bridge_text` is declared as `char *`. This is not a string class as other languages have - it is simply a pointer to some memory that is to be read as a sequence of `char`s.

By assigning other values to `bridge_text` you have lost its original value (and therefore leaked the memory you `malloc`'d) and pointed it at another part of memory. This is why your program crashes when you try to `free(bridge_text)` - the pointer is no longer valid for freeing.

Also, as an aside, the `sizeof` operator gets the byte size of whatever you pass it - in this case a, presumably, integer constant - so you are actually only allocating 5 or 9 bytes (depending on system), not `(LEN + 1)`.

You have a number of options to fix your code:

- Don't dynamically allocate your `char` buffer. Change the declaration to `char bridge_text[LEN + 1]` and remove the `malloc` and `free` calls. Then use `strcpy` to populate it with data.
- Simply use bridge_text as a pointer to other buffers containing items you want to print. This works if everything is constant or you put anything dynamic in a separate buffer (don't forget to make sure your dynamic buffer doesn't go out of scope though), e.g.

  ```
  char dynamic_string [50];
  int value = 10;
  sprintf(dynamic_string,"Value = %d", value);
  bridge_text = dynamic_string;
  ```
- Keep using it as you are but fix your `malloc` size issue and change the `bridge_text = <something>` to `strcpy(bridge_text,<something>)`.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of line:

```
bridge_text = north;
```

does not copy the text string in north[] to the char array bridge_text[].

it only copies pointers..

suggest:

```
strcpy( bridge_text, north );
```

in the current code, the malloc'd pointer in bridge_text is being overlayed by the assignment statements.

That is why the free() causes an abort.

suggest using 'strcpy()' to copy the strings into where bridge_text points