# In C, free half of the memory chunk, without freeing the other half

Tags: c, malloc, free

If I have allocated a memory chunk say

```
char *a =(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
```

and I do

```
strcpy( "string of len 5",a);
```

then is there a way to free the left over part of my memory chunk?
In other scenario if I do

```
strcpy("string of len5", (a+5));
```

then first half will be empty. is there a way to `free()` that first part without deallocating the second half?

Please don't suggest `realloc()` as it allocates a new chunk of memory copy content there and release the previous.(AKAIK).

Comment: "Please don't suggest `realloc()`" – it's exactly `realloc()` that you should use.

Comment: Got any problem with `realloc()` ?

Comment: If the reason for "don't suggest `realloc`" is because there are multiple aliased copies of that pointer floating around which would potentially be invalidated by a call to realloc - well, don't keep multiple aliased copies of pointers laying around. Programming requires discipline. Best of luck.

Comment: BTW `sizeof(char)` is redundant, it is guaranteed to be 1 by the standard.

Comment: and in C you [don't cast the result of `malloc`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: ^^^ what @BobJarvis says.  Even if you could deallocate half the space without realloc, the other pointer aliases would not know about it and so any other functions/threads operating with the aliased pointers would likely UB themselves to death.  Try very hard to not design bad code/data.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no way you can `free()` *half* or *part* of the dynamically allocated memory. You need to `free()` it *all* at a time.

While getting the memory through dynamic memory allocation, you basically get a pointer. You need to pass the *exact* pointer to `free()`. Passing a pointer to `free()` which is not returned by `malloc()` or family, is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FYI, see this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876929/2173917).

Answer (score 4):

`realloc()` isn't required to copy and a *good* implementation avoids unnecessary copies. You should really rely on that. (to clarify: for performance reasons, of course. Always assume an implementation *may* take a copy)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void *test1 = malloc(16);
    void *test2 = realloc(test1, 8);
    free(test2);

    printf("malloc: %x -- realloc: %x\n", test1, test2);
    return 0;
}
```

example output:

> malloc: 4779c0 -- realloc: 4779c0

Answer (score 2):

The `malloc(3)` API doesn't allow this, other than with `realloc(3)`.  In common implementations, shrinking with realloc (usually?) won't trigger a copy, and esp. not if the buffer was large.

If you really want to be able to guarantee non-copying, implement your own allocator on top of POSIX `mmap(2)` / `munmap(2)`.  You can unmap part of a mapping without affecting the pages that weren't in the address range given.

Answer (score 1):

Without using realloc it is impossible to do the task in the frames of the C Standard. There is nothing complicated in using realloc.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how it can be done

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HELLO_WORLD "Hello World"

int main( void )
{
    char *s;
    size_t n = sizeof( HELLO_WORLD );

    s = malloc( n );

    strcpy( s, HELLO_WORLD );

    puts( s );

    memmove( s, s + 6, n - 6 ); 

    puts( s );

    char *t = realloc( s, n - 6 );

    if ( t ) s = t;

    puts( s );

    free( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
World
World
```

Another approach is to copy simply the substring in another allocated string. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HELLO_WORLD "Hello World"

int main( void )
{
    char *s;
    size_t n = sizeof( HELLO_WORLD );

    s = malloc( n );

    strcpy( s, HELLO_WORLD );

    puts( s );

    do
    {
        char *t = malloc( n - 6 );

        if ( t )
        {
            strcpy( t, s + 6 );
            free( s );
            s = t;
        }
    } while( 0 );        

    puts( s );

    free( s );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World
World
```

Answer (score 0):

there is no way for you to do this, and is there any necessary to free half? it is not safe at all.  Dynamically allocated memory must be free all.

Answer (score -1):

> Call to malloc when succeed in returning a logically contiguous block of memory from your program's HEAP memory space just bit more  than what you requested.

This  extra memory which is used to store information such as the size of the allocated block, and a link to the next free/used block in a chain of blocks.

When you free your pointer, it uses that address to find the special information it added to the beginning (usually) of your allocated block.

So therefore you can't free memory less than what you allocated using `malloc`.If you pass different address it will give undefined behaviour.

For this purpose `realloc` is used .