# Memory Allocation and Deallocation in C

Tags: c

I am allocating memory to a void * of some specific size. After allocating I want to show a memory leak and want to deallocate that memory but to some particular size given.

For example : I have allocated memory of 1000bytes using malloc now I want to deallocate 500 bytes of this 1000 bytes.

How can i do that?

Thank you and Regards

Comment: It's simply not possible, you can't free just half a memory chunk you have allocated. It's all or nothing. And to simulate a memory leak, why not just don't free the memory at all?

Comment: The best you can do is allocate a new chunk of memory, then free the old one.

Comment: [Not an exact dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27876923/2173917), but can provide some insight.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to `free` just some memory from allocated one. But have option of `realloc` is attempts to **resize the memory block** pointed to by ptr that was previously allocated with a call to malloc or calloc.

```
void func()
{
        //allocate 1000 byte
    void *ptr = malloc(1000);

        //reallocate with new size 
    ptr = realloc(ptr ,500);
        //Now you have memory of 500 byte


      //free memory after use
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to deallocate just 500 bytes out of 1000bytes allocated.

`free()` function takes pointer returned by only `malloc()` and its family functions for allocation. So it will free all the memory allocated.

If your purpose is to show memory leak then

```
void func()
{
  void *p =  malloc(1000);
  // Some stuff
  return;
}
```

Memory allocated is not freed here and you have a memory leak.