# Binary to Decimal segmentation error

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

I am using a pointer in place of an array, I'm aware that a pointer needs to be freed unlike an array. Why is it that using a pointer in place of an array gives me a segmentation memory error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>

void bin(void){

char *input;
int choice;
int x = 0;


    printf("Enter Decimal Code:\n");
    scanf("%s",&input);

    int leng = strlen(input);



    for(int i = 0; i <= leng ; ++i){

        if(input[i] == '1'){
            x += pow(2,i);


        }
        else if(input[i] == '0'){
            input[i] = 0;


        }
        free(input);

    }
        printf("Binary-Dec: %d\n",x);


}

int main()
{
bin();

}
```

Comment: A pointer only needs to be freed if it points to the beginning of a dynamically allocated block of data. Your pointer points nowhere good. So you can't pass it to `scanf`.

Comment: @juanchopanza How would  I be able to pass it through scanf/ is there an alternative

Comment: Do not add tags for different languages.

Comment: What are all those useless blank lines for ?

Comment: @robinhood46 You need to figure out what a pointer is (hint: there is a clue in the name) and you need to read some documentation for `scanf` (particularly what it assumes about the pointer you pass to it.)

Comment: `char *input;` is a pointer that points to nowhere.

Comment: You've missed the fact that a pointer needs to point to something - it's not a magical array replacement that conjures storage out of pixie dust when needed. It's also not true that all pointers need to be freed. I suggest that you get yourself a [good](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: http://ideone.com/idR4xn

Comment: @juanchopanza to my understanding a pointer is a variable which points to a specific place in memory?

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you, all I had to do was replace %s with %ms wow

Comment: @robinhood46 `%ms` is not standard. (by glibc [scanf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf))

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
 scanf("%s",&input);
```

is the problematic part. There are two issues, as I can see.

- First, `input` being a pointer, `&input` is the address of the pointer.
- Second, even if you remove the `&`, as the `input` is not allocated memory, it will still lead to [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should rather do

```
 char input[32] = {0};
 scanf("%31s", input);   //limit the input buffer to prevent overflow
```

Also, it's advisable that you check for the return value of `scanf()` for success to ensure proper input.

---

FWIW, for the statement

> *[...]I'm aware that a pointer needs to be freed[..]*

Right, but only when they are allocated memory dynamically through `malloc()` or family of functions. consider the below scenario,

```
char buf[32] = {0};
char *input = buf;
. . . .
```

in this case, you need not `free()` input in any way, as the memory is not allocated dynamically. For more info, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876929/2173917).

Comment: In addition, calling `free()` on a pointer which does not point at dynamically allocated memory will most likely cause the program to crash, since it too is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Because your pointer is `unitialized`, therefore `undefined behaviour` will occur and your code may or may not work.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5870038/uninitialized-pointers-in-code) for more information.

Answer (score -1):

All I had to do was to replace

```
   scanf("%s",&input);
```

with

```
   scanf("%ms",&input);
```

Thanks to BLUEPIXY

Comment: No, this does not solve the numerous severe bugs you still have in your program. Undefined behavior is tricky: the program might seem to work now, then suddenly crash next time you run it. You really need to read and understand the other answers posted. You have at least 3 severe bugs which may cause program crashes.