# C - pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: c, memory, free

I am trying to free a pointer that I assigned from a vector allocated with `malloc()`, when I try to remove the first element(index [0]), it works, when I try to remove the second(index [1]) I receive this error:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x100200218: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

The code:

```
table->t = malloc (sizeof (entry) * tam);
entry * elem = &table->t[1];
free(elem);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only call (or need to) `free()` on the pointer returned by `malloc()` and family.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.22.3.3

> [...] Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management
>   function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to `free` or `realloc`, the
>   behavior is undefined.

In your case, `table->t` (or, `&table->t[0]`) is that pointer, not `&table->t[1]`.

That said, `free()`-ing `table->t` frees the *whole* memory block, you don't need to (you can't, rather) free individually/ partially. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27876923/2173917) for more info.

Comment: Maybe add that freeing `&table->t[0]` only works because it is equivalent to `table->t`.

Answer (score 3):

It works on the first element because *&table->t[0]* is equal to *table->t*. That's because the first element has the same address as the array itself (by definition of the array). 
And since the array itself has an address that has been allocated, only that one can be freed.

Answer (score 1):

malloc() works by allocating a single contiguous memory area, whose usable size is the single integer parameter passed by it. It returns a pointer for the allocated area.

You can only free the returned pointer once, and not a subset of it.

Arrays aren't objects in C, they're syntatic sugar to pointer arithmetic, which is probably the main headache of C programming and the area you should carefully study if you're committed to learning C.