# Why does not free() deallocate all allocated memory locations?

Tags: c, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

I don't know if I am doing something wrong or if my concept is somewhat wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
     int *p;
     p=calloc(3,sizeof(int));
     p[0]=10;
     p[1]=15;
     p[2]=30;
     printf("\n%d\n%p\n%d\n%p\n%d\n%p\n\n",p[0],p,p[1],p+1,p[2],p+2);
     free(p);
     //p=NULL;
     printf("\n%d\n%p\n%d\n%p\n%d\n%p\n\n",p[0],p,p[1],p+1,p[2],p+2);
     return 0;
}
```

When the 2nd, printf() is run, it shows p[2]=30, whereas p[0]=p[1]=0 (in gcc ubuntu and some arbitary values in Code::Blocks windows). I have 2 questions.

1. Why free() frees first 2 pointers and not the 3rd. one?
2. Why are the values shown 0 in ubuntu when it seems right to show arbitary values?

I am a beginner so please bear with me. I have tried the same thing with malloc(), and same thing happens.

Comment: `free` *has* freed the memory. But it doesn't magically cease to exist. It just hasn't yet been re-used by another process, or function. And there are not 3 pointers, just 1.

Comment: If the memory is really free()-d how does p[3] retain it's original value? I agree it is undefined behavior and hence it should give arbitary values, right?

Comment: @StephenStemmer define arbitrary.

Comment: @StephenStemmer `free`ing memory makes it available for re-use, that's all. That does not give it "arbitrary values". It's just available for re-use, and whatever values are written to it *then* will be to all intents arbitrary as far as your continued use is concerned. Some or all of it might have been reallocated within `printf`. But it's useless to speculate.

Comment: hehe, it does have an arbitrary value. How would you know if it's *unarbitrary?*

Comment: @DigitalRoss well yes, but my point was that when you `free` memory it is not "given" an arbitrary value. OP should know that it is *undefined behaviour* to access freed memory, that's all.

Comment: Yeah, that was for Stephen. Those @OP tags are redundant, as the OP is automatically notified.

Comment: @StephenStemmer, why would you expect values in free()d memory to change? wouldn't it be a total waste of time?  If I hand you a glass of water and say "this is yours now", do you automatically dump it on the floor or fill it  with something else?  "Free" just means "doesn't belong you anymore". It doesn't mean there's any reason for it to change.

Answer (score 6):

Using memory that has already been `free()`-d invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). ***Don't do that.***

Quoting `C11`, annex §J.2, *Undefined behavior*

> The value of a pointer that refers to space deallocated by a call to the `free` or
>   `realloc` function is used.

To elaborate, calling `free()` on a pointer does not set the pointer to `NULL` or anything else. It just marks the memory as re-usable by the memory manager. That memory location (pointer) is not *valid* anymore for the program, so you should not be using it.

As a preventive measure to the above problem, it's considered a good coding practice to set the pointer to `NULL` explicitly after calling `free()`. However, FWIW, this is not *mandatory*.

Quoting `C11`, chapter 7.22.3.3

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. [...]

Also, just to add, *partial `free()`* is not possible by calling `free()`, anyway. You can [refer to this previous answer for clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27876923/2173917).

Comment: Hence, you should always set your freed pointers to null after freeing them.

Comment: @Tyler not a mandate, but a good practice, I agree. :)