# Free first element of array

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free

When I allocate an array using `malloc`, is there a way to only free the first element(s) of the array?

A small example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char * a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    strcpy(a, "foo bar");

    // How I would have to do this.
    char * b = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
    strcpy(b, a+1);


    free(a);
    free(b);
}
```

Is there a way to free just the first char of `a`, so that I can use the rest of the string using `a+1`?

Comment: No you cant free only one byte of array. You can free only pointer returned from `malloc`, which points on the first byte of allocated array, and as well, it will free all the allocated array of bytes. Anyway you can realloc it to size you want, which can be more or less bytes then actuall size.

Comment: More importantly, why????

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27876929/2173917) Dupe???

Comment: You could work with another pointer, with `char *b = a + 1;` and later on, you just `free(a);`

Comment: @WeatherVane I know. I was just wondering if that would be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to remove the first character of `a`, you could use `memmove()` to move the remainder of the characters in the string to the left by 1, and you could use `realloc()` to shrink the allocation if desired:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
    strcpy(a, "foo bar");

    puts(a);

    size_t rest = strlen(a);

    memmove(a, a+1, rest);

    /* If you must reallocate */
    char *temp = realloc(a, rest);
    if (temp == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to reallocate");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    a = temp;

    puts(a);

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

### Update

@chux has made a couple of [good points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758354/free-first-element-of-array/45758716#comment78475947_45758716) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758354/free-first-element-of-array/45758716#comment78476052_45758716).

First, instead of exiting on a failure in `realloc()`, it may be better to simply continue without reassigning `temp` to `a`; after all, `a` does point to the expected string anyway, the allocated memory would just be a little larger than necessary.

Second, if the input string is empty, then `rest` will be 0. This leads to problems with `realloc(a, rest)`. One solution would be to check for `rest == 0` before modifying the string pointed to by `a`.

Here is a slightly more general version of the above code that incorporates these suggestions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *s = "foo bar";
    char *a = malloc(sizeof *a * (strlen(s) + 1));
    strcpy(a, s);

    puts(a);

    size_t rest = strlen(a);

    /* Don't do anything if a is an empty string */
    if (rest) {
        memmove(a, a+1, rest);

        /* If you must reallocate */
        char *temp = realloc(a, rest);
        if (temp) {
            a = temp;
        }
    }

    puts(a);

    free(a);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: This is a case where code could use `if (temp) { a = temp; }` for on a rare  failure of shrinking an allocation, simply enough to not update `a`.

Comment: Note: Additional considerations needed when `rest == 0`.  OP's intent is unclear in this case.

Comment: @chux-- those are both good points; I have added an update to my answer to incorporate your suggestions.

Comment: A downvote with comment may be helpful; a downvote without comment (on a post that is three months old, no less) is just mysterious.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to free just the first char of a

No. You can not free the first character of `a` because it is of char type. Only pointer returned by `malloc` family function can be freed.
You can do this though.

```
char * a = malloc(sizeof(char) * 8);
strcpy(a, "foo bar");
char * b = malloc(strlen(a));
strcpy(b, a+1);
free(a);
```